# Import Classes from Modules of Python Package to __init__

Tags: python, python-packaging

In the Python package that I am working on there is a sub-package within it which contains a bunch of modules. Each module consists of a class.

Now, this package is meant to be extensible and there can be new modules introduced anytime. Similar to the existing modules, any new module introduced will also consist of their own class.

I want all of the classes in these modules to be imported to the **init** file of the sub-package.

Is there a way that I can do this automatically, so that I don't have to change the **init** file each time a new module is created?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution. It's a bit hacky but I guess this is what you're looking for.

You can agree on a specific attribute which points to your class in all new modules (here `export_class`). Then you need to iterate over all the modules inside their directory and dynamically import them and then get the class you're interested in.

This code can be further tuned to meet your needs:

mod1.py:

```py
class C1:
    pass

export_class = C1
```

mod2.py:

```py
class C2:
    pass

export_class = C2
```

__init__.py:

```py
import importlib
import os.path
import sys

# Location of all new modules
directory = os.path.dirname(__file__)
sys.path.append(directory)

for file in os.listdir(directory):
    # Add other constraints here
    if file.endswith(".py") and not file.startswith("_"):
        # Import the module
        m = importlib.import_module(file.removesuffix(".py"))

        cls = m.export_class
        globals()[cls.__name__] = cls

sys.path.remove(directory)
```

Now when your package is imported, `C1` and `C2` are available in its namespace.

One downside to this is that type checkers will complain when you access `C1` and `C2`. It can't find them.